# How to avoid NaN in using ReLU + Cross-Entropy?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, autoencoders

ReLU has a range of [0, +Inf). So, when it comes an activation value z=0/1 produced by ReLU or softplus, the loss value computed by cross-entropy : loss = -(x*ln(z)+(1-x)*ln(1-z)) will turn to NaN.
As i know, my variables are run in theano.tensor type which cannot be modified after defined. So, I cannot simply change the values in z which are 0/1 into some approximate (such as 0.001/0.999).
How to avoid this annoying situation without replacing the cross-entropy by MSE?

Comment: In Scala this would just return `Infinity`, but if your not using such an awesome language you'll have to change your cross-entropy function to be an tenary expression to handle the 0

Answer (score 5):

The recommended thing to do when using ReLUs is to clip the gradient, if the norm is above a certain threshold, during the SGD update (suggested by Mikolov, see http://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.5063.pdf)

This requires another hyperparameter, the threshold. The suggestion from the referenced paper is to sample some gradients to get an idea of the (non-exploding) norm and use the sample average. From my limited experience, it is worth playing around with this parameter a bit, even up to half the sample average.

Pseudocode looks like,

```
if norm(grad) > threshold:
   grad = grad * threshold/norm(grad)
```